# Moving N Kings on chess board

Tags: algorithm, chess

Suppose we have a chessboard (of arbitrary size) and N kings initially placed on N squares. Let's suppose now we select N new squares to move the kings to through a sequence of legal moves (no collisions). The goal would be to minimize the total distance moved by all kings. I can't really think of an algorithm/adaptation that could handle moving all pieces while taking care of preventing "colliding" kings. The algorithm should be faster than recursively selecting target squares and selecting the minimum transport. I'm hopeful someone has invaluable advice on this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, collision here means two pieces on the same square, rather than adjacency or ability to capture in chess?

Comment: Do all kings move together at each step? Do all the kings need to move at each step?  Or can they stand still while on their way?  Are the target squares assigned to individual kings, or is it up to the algorithm to decide which king should go to which target? The problem can get very tricky when the board is close to full.

Comment: The player can only move one king at a time with no captures and hence is not allowed to collide with other pieces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to find a minimum total distance complete bipartite matching between all the kings and all the target squares.  You can recast this as a [maximum weight bipartite matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) by replacing each distance with weight (something_big-distance), and then finding a maximum weight bipartite matching, or you can just maintain the invariant that the matching is complete and find the minimum bipartite matching directly.

I think the easiest way to do this is with the [Edmonds-Karp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).  This is normally used for finding a maximum flow, but maximum weight bipartite matching is essentially an instance of that problem, once you add single source and sink vertices.

Once you've found the matching between kings and their target squares, you can move the kings.  It doesn't make a lot of difference what order you make them in as long as you move each king along its shortest path, and you don't move a king onto an already occupied square.  If a king wants to move onto an occupied square, there are  two choices:

1. If the king-in-the-way is not already at its target square, then just move that one instead.
2. If the king-in-the-way is already on its target square, then swap targets between the king you want to move and the king-in-the-way.  Then just move the king-in-the-way. This doesn't change the total number of moves you have to make.

Of course, the king-in-the-way might also have a king in *its* way, so apply these rules again until you get to one you can move.

Now you might be wondering about what to do if *every king* that has to move has a king it its way.  That could only happen if there's a cycle where all the kings want to move around the cycle... but this *cannot* happen.

Moving all the kings around a cycle costs moves, but it doesn't change the state of the board.  Such a condition would therefore imply that the set of paths you found in your original mapping are *not* minimal.  Since they *are* minimal, such a condition is impossible.

Comment: Very nice. I was having trouble recasting this in terms of matching, but the cycle argument clarifies any ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm should work:

1. Find the target square that is farther away from its nearest king.
2. Move the nearest king to that square.  (No blocking can occur because a king must be closer to block another king)
3. Repeat until all kings have been moved to a target.

It may be possible for a king on its target to block an unmoved king in #2, but I’m not sure that this can happen.

---

Upon further reflection, it is clear to me that my algorithm above is more like a Greedy Method heuristic, than a deterministic solution.  I can easily come up with an example for which it fails to produce an optimal solution.

Consider when N=4 on a [(1 to 5)x(1 to 5)] board with:

- K = {(2,2), (3,4), (4,3), (5,5)}, and
- T = {(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (3,3)}

My algorithm will first try to move one of K:{(2,2), (3,4), (4,3)} to T:(3,3), which is wrong.  It should move K:(5,5) to T:(3,3) and probably not first.

Comment: So we must group squares based off their nearest king to find the square furthest to the east for each king?

Comment: @Ian_L Sorry, that’s a typo.  “*Furtherest away*”

Comment: ♚T♚T. You need to move the right king to the right, then the left king to the right. The proposed algorithm does not select the correct sequence.